# Need help about Google group

Tags: account-management, google-groups

1. How long Google group can store uploaded file? Will they be auto deleted after sometime?
2. I earlier created a group and tried to post some stuff. Because of the server being slow, I deleted the group. The problem is with the incomplete post still present in my search query. I want to create that group by same name but from my different Google account but I am unable to do this. Google says that account is already in use. Although I have deleted my account the data is present in search query.

Any one can give idea what I have to do?

Comment: It's best to have just one question in a question post.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can understand what your problems are...

- You want to know how long attachments are kept in a Google Group?

As long as Google doesn't warn you that the file will be deleted, I think they will last as long as the message they are attached to. Just like in Gmail, attachments will not get lost as long as you don't delete the message they were send with.

- You created a groups with a name, deleted it and want to create a new one with the same name?

Many services block usernames once they are used. Most probably Google Groups does that too, so you will never be able to use that username again if you deleted the group. The reason why they do this is to avoid the circumstance in which some people keep mailing to a deleted group and that someone else that recreated the group will see their messages.

Answer (score 0):

1. As Steven said, Google won't delete your files unless you do it.
2. > The problem is with the incomplete post still present in my search query.Although I have deleted my account the data is present in search query.

What do you mean by search query here? If you are sure you have deleted your group, then there is no way of your past data existing in any form.

> I want to create that group by same name but from my different Google account

You can create the Group with same name from any Google account(provided your previous group is deleted, not disabled). I myself tried this after your question and was able to create a group with same name and address from 2nd Google account, while my first group is deleted.